# PostgreSQL query not returning result as intended

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to generate a list of all days where every sailor booked a boat in that particular day.

The table scheme is as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE SAILOR(
SID INTEGER NOT NULL,
NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
RATING INTEGER NOT NULL,
AGE FLOAT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(SID)
);

CREATE TABLE BOAT(
BID INTEGER NOT NULL,
NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
COLOR VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(BID)
);

CREATE TABLE RESERVE (
SID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES SAILOR(SID),
BID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES BOAT(BID),
DAY DATE NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(SID, BID, DAY));
```

The data is as follows:

```sql
INSERT INTO SAILOR(SID, NAME, RATING, AGE)
VALUES
  (64, 'Horatio', 7, 35.0),
  (74, 'Horatio', 9, 35.0);

INSERT INTO BOAT(BID, NAME, COLOR)
VALUES
  (101, 'Interlake', 'blue'),
  (102, 'Interlake', 'red'),
  (103, 'Clipper', 'green'),
  (104, 'Marine', 'red');

INSERT INTO RESERVE(SID, BID, DAY)
VALUES+
  (64, 101, '09/05/98'),
  (64, 102, '09/08/98'),
  (74, 103, '09/08/98');
```

I have tried using this code:

```sql
SELECT DAY
FROM RESERVE R
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT SID
FROM SAILOR S
EXCEPT
SELECT S.SID
FROM SAILOR S, RESERVE R
WHERE S.SID = R.SID)
GROUP BY DAY;
```

but it returns a list of all days, no exception. The only day that it should return is "09/08/98". How do I solve this?

Comment: Note: `PRIMARY KEY(SID, BID, DAY));` is wrong. it allows a boat to be lended multiple times on a single date(or: a person to lease multiple ships on a single day)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would phrase your query as:

```
SELECT r.DAY
FROM RESERVE r
GROUP BY r.DAY
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT r.SID) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SAILOR);
```

### Demo

The above query says to return any day in the `RESERVE` table whose distinct `SID` sailor count matches the count of every sailor.

This assumes that `SID` sailor entries in the `RESERVE` table would only be made with sailors that actually appear in the `SAILOR` table.  This seems reasonable, and can be enforced using primary/foreign key relationships between the two tables.

Comment: @RafaelPintodeFreitas . . . This was the first answer by over 15 minutes.  It includes an explanation and a demo.  I think this is the better answer and deserves to be accepted.

Comment: Sorry to revive the dead post, but you're right, @GordonLinoff! Thank you for the answer, Tim!

Answer (score 1):

Taking a slightly different approach of just counting unique sailors per day:

```sql
SELECT day FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sid), day FROM reserve GROUP BY day
) AS sailors_per_day
WHERE count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sailor);
```

```
+------------+
| day        |
|------------|
| 1998-09-08 |
+------------+
```